# Creating a simple search functionality

Tags: javascript, arrays, android-studio, android-intent, searchview

I was trying to understand how to make a search functions in an app. I go through the Creating a Search Interface documentation, but its quite hard and yea i need help. However, i do succeed to just create a search interface, displaying results based from a string arrray. It does work, but it doesnt had any activity behind it or any intent. It more like a simple text-search. I just wondering can i put int that can simultaneously work with string ?

Or any solution and ideas, really appreciate it.

for now here is my homefragment class

```
package com.example.testtt;

import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        //define
        RelativeLayout drawerlayouthome;
        ListView list;
        ListViewAdapter adapter;
        SearchView editsearch;
        ArrayList<DoaSearchIndex> arrayList = new ArrayList<DoaSearchIndex>();




        String[] doasearchindex = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doasearchindex);

        //locatelistview
        list = v.findViewById(R.id.searchlistview);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < doasearchindex.length; i++) {
            DoaSearchIndex doaSearchIndex = new DoaSearchIndex(doasearchindex[i]);

            arrayList.add(doaSearchIndex);
        }

        //pass result to listviewadapter.class

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this.getActivity(), arrayList);

        //binds adapter to listview

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //locatesearchview

        editsearch = v.findViewById(R.id.searchview);

        editsearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                    list.clearTextFilter();
                    adapter.filter("");
                    list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    adapter.filter(newText);
                    list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        drawerlayouthome = v.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layouthome);
        drawerlayouthome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                editsearch.clearFocus();
            }
        });





        //definingcardview

        CardView doacard = v.findViewById(R.id.doacard);
        CardView ziarahcard = v.findViewById(R.id.ziarahcard);

        //setcardviewlistener

        doacard.setOnClickListener(this);
        ziarahcard.setOnClickListener(this);






        return v;

    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i ;

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.doacard:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), listdoa.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
            case R.id.ziarahcard:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), listziarah.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

and my listviewadapter

```
package com.example.testtt;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //Declare variables first

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<DoaSearchIndex> doaSearchIndexList = null;
    private ArrayList<DoaSearchIndex> arrayList;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<DoaSearchIndex> doaSearchIndexList) {
        mContext = context;
        this.doaSearchIndexList = doaSearchIndexList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<DoaSearchIndex>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(doaSearchIndexList);
    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return doaSearchIndexList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public DoaSearchIndex getItem(int position) {
        return doaSearchIndexList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.name.setText(doaSearchIndexList.get(position).getDoaSearchIndex());
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        doaSearchIndexList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            doaSearchIndexList.addAll(arrayList);
        } else {
            for (DoaSearchIndex wp : arrayList) {
                if (wp.getDoaSearchIndex().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    doaSearchIndexList.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

and my doasearchindex class

```
package com.example.testtt;

public class DoaSearchIndex {

    private String doaSearchIndex;

    public DoaSearchIndex(String doaSearchIndex) {
        this.doaSearchIndex = doaSearchIndex;
    }

    public String getDoaSearchIndex() {
        return this.doaSearchIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Thanks, i already put the code.